# Does `ntfsclone --save-image' attempt to read bad sectors?

Tags: ntfs, cloning

I'm migrating from an HDD with NTFS that has a number of bad sectors.

I've just run `chkdsk /r` (from [ERD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680675.aspx) 6.0 x32) on it to make sure they all are properly marked as such.

Yet, when running `ntfsclone --save-image <...>` without `--rescue` (from [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org) 4.6.0), I get *"the disk has N bad sectors"* warning (which is fine) but then - `ERROR: the disk is faulty <...>`.

The questions are:

- What does the error mean? Does it just mean that `ntfsclone` reads all the sectors (rather than only those containing data) regardless of the `--save-image` flag and bumped into the 1st bad one (so the user data is perfectly fine, and the backup with `--rescue` would still be sound) or that I've got yet another, unmarked bad sector?
- If it's the former, can `ntfsclone` be directed to ignore marked bads and only choke on unmarked ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with the developer, this [proved to be a bug in `ntfsclone` and `ntfsresize` `v2015.3.14`](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=38976#p38976): they are indeed supposed to be bypassing bad clusters, but don't do so if there are too many of them for the list to fit into a single block.

The developer provided a patch for the current release, `ntfs-3g v2015.3.14`, that's available on the above link.